# Why doesn't this Nested Serializer(ForeignKey) work?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class RFIDReaderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RFIDReader
        bind_state_choice = ProductEntityStateChoiceSerializer()
        # depth = 2
        fields = (
            "url", "pk", "reader_name", "reader_host", "reader_address", "reader_ip", "reader_port",
            "bind_state_choice",
            "bind_state_location"
        )
```

[Serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Joovd.png)

[Nested Serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZEXA.png)

[Model Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gspFi.png)

[RestFul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW1ai.png)

Answer (score 1):

Any modification on any field should be outside of meta

```py
class RFIDReaderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    bind_state_choice = ProductEntityStateChoiceSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = RFIDReader
        # depth = 2
        fields = (
            "url", "pk", "reader_name", "reader_host", "reader_address", "reader_ip", "reader_port",
            "bind_state_choice",
            "bind_state_location"
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. May be I need a rubber duck.